# Concatenate variables in string with "@" symbol

Tags: c#, string-concatenation

Given this multi-line string:

```
string strProviderJSON = @"
                {
                    ""npi"":""1111111111"",
                    ""name"":""DME Clearinghouse"",
                    ""email"":""my@doc.como"",
                    ""contactName"":""Sally Smith"",
                    ""fax"":"""",
                    ""address"":{
                        ""country"":""United States"",
                        ""street1"":""27787 Dequindre Apt 616"",
                        ""street2"":"""",
                        ""city"":""Madison Heights"",
                        ""state"":""MI"",
                        ""zipCode"":""32003""
                    },
                    ""phone"":""(904) 739-0300"",
                    ""contactPhone"":""(904) 739-0300""
                }
            ";
```

How do I concatenate a variable in there? I tried this, but keep getting an error:

```
string strTest = "1111111111";
string strProviderJSON = @"
                {
                    ""npi"":""" + strTest + """,
                    ""name"":""DME Clearinghouse"",
                    ""email"":""my@doc.como"",
                    ""contactName"":""Sally Smith"",
                    ""fax"":"""",
                    ""address"":{
                        ""country"":""United States"",
                        ""street1"":""27787 Dequindre Apt 616"",
                        ""street2"":"""",
                        ""city"":""Madison Heights"",
                        ""state"":""MI"",
                        ""zipCode"":""32003""
                    },
                    ""phone"":""(904) 739-0300"",
                    ""contactPhone"":""(904) 739-0300""
                }
            ";
```

Comment: Use a JSON library!!! Those double quotes are hideous and there's no good reason for it that I can think of

Comment: @JoePhilllips which would you recommend? I take it I'd have to make an object out of that whole string up there then pass it to a JSON library?

Comment: newtonsoft json is the usual for c#. You could even make an anonymous object and use that. Pretty simple and will clean up your code a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Affix another `@` character to the start of the next string literal.

```
...
""npi"":""" + strTest + @"""
""name"": ""DME Clearinghouse"",
...
```

Answer (score 1):

For string concatenation you should use **String.Format()** method as **normal concatenation creates multiple strings in memory** so String.Format() will help you in easy way to insert variables.

Example :

```
String s = "111111";
String finalString = String.Format(@""npi"":""{0}"",s);
```

This was for single line (You can use multiple line but that would not be readable).
Now for multi line you can use **StringBuilder** class which provides us lot of functions like **Append()**, **AppendFormat()** etc. so using it you can have a readable code

Example :

```
StringBuilder tempString = new StringBuilder();
tempString.Append("{\n");
tempString.AppendFormat(@"""npi"":""{0}"",\n", npiString);// npiString is a variable
tempString.AppendFormat(@"""name"":""{0}"",\n", nameString);// nameString is a variable
.....
// you should add variables like this
// at the end you can store final string by using following
String finalString = tempString.ToString();
```

Note : I have not used these '"' many times in String so not sure with that, but appending a variable should be done by **StringBuilder**.

Hope somewhere it will help you to achieve your GOAL.

Comment: This is true only when concatenating inside a loop.  For a single statement concatenating a bunch of string literals and variables, the compiler emits a single call to the very efficient framework Concat method.  For such a scenario, StringBuilder is unnecessarily verbose, cumbersome, and difficult to read, and it is possibly even *less* efficient.

Comment: @phoog can you please help me to know more about this as I am not that much aware of this. As much I know when we use '+' to concatenate in memory a new string with the result of each '+' will create i.e. if we used 3 '+' then we would have 4 strings in memory and final string will be pointed by our reference string.

Comment: But that's true of a string builder, too.  You have the three input strings, and the output string, for a total of four strings. Plus you have allocated the string builder, which Concat does not do.  Jon Skeet has written about this: http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/stringbuilder.html

Comment: Yes, Thanx for this. I got one more efficient tech to concat. But the example that has been taken in case of string builder I will use AppendFormat() method which will give me result in one line only. Here Que is related to multiple lines. Can you help us that how will you use this Concat in above case.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.  AppendFormat is cumbersome.  The multi-line example in the question is more readable as it is closer to the format of the actual data.  It is many lines, but it is one statement.  That is, it's logically a single method call.  To use Concat, the programmer uses the + operator.  The compiler translates that to the Concat method call.

Comment: The op should just be using a json library anyway so this conversation is sort of philosophical. Especially considering the strings are tiny and it will be a negligible performance boost no matter what you do

Comment: Ok got it. Thanx @phoog.